# Which is more efficient

Tags: java, android, arrays

This is something I thought up for assigning a group of consecutive buttons. I like this style but would it be more efficient to do individual buttons with find by id ?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < NanoConstants.NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS;i++){ //assign buttons
        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("project_button_" + String.valueOf(i), "id", getPackageName()));
        addButton.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.project_names)[i]);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mProjectButtons.add(addButton);
    }
```

Thanks Everyone !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this code appears to run once on application start-up I would avoid trying to micro-optimize it. Stick with the style that makes the code the most readable.

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't be. `for` loops are just as efficient as the unrolled versions, are much better for readability, and reduce code and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the buttons in a groupview and looping its childs with getChildAt 
and check the view if it is a button, like below:

```
int childCnt = viewGroup.getChildCount();
for(int i=0;i<childCnt;i++){
  View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
  if(view instanceof Button){
    Button button = (Button)view;
    addButton.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.project_names)[i]);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mProjectButtons.add(addButton);
  }
}
```

Even now if you added a button no need to change this code, just add it in the layout and add a value in the array.

But as Elliott Frisch said:

> Since this code appears to run once on application start-up I would
>   avoid trying to micro-optimize it. Stick with the style that makes the
>   code the most readable.